# What activation function to use in regression task when your target has upper and lower limit

Tags: keras, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to do a regression task using keras and my target is number of days between 0 and 15.

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1276, input_dim=1276, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100,kernel_initializer='normal' ,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
# Compile model
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(loss=rmse, optimizer=optimizer)
# Fit the model
model.fit(X,y , validation_split=0.33, epochs=100, batch_size=512)
```

When I train this model I get very large values. I am wondering if I am missing something in my implementation. Should I use a specific activation function for this kind of problems ?

Comment: I would scale the output data by 1/15, so it takes values between 0 and 1, and use "sigmoid" activation.

Comment: I also think of sigmoid. Or maybe consider it like classification task with 15 options? in this case you can use 15 output units and pick option with highest activation (e.g. using 'argmax' func)

Comment: You could also try to run it with different batch sizes and try a different loss function. Run several experiments to observe what parameters take you in the right way.